# php check ( if node exists ) in sxml feed

Tags: php

I have a PHP "foreach" script that runs to pull all the uploaded videos **( with related data for each )** from a selected YouTube channel. Then I am able to select the video I wish.
Now I have asked on the youtube forum, but they are reluctant to help outside of thier dedicated api.

So far I have only had this with a single youtube channel, but for my site to work, I need to know that **ALL** channels will work.

Right..... This is the problem.
This is what I get.

***Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in xxxxxxxx.php on line 24
Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in xxxxxxxx.php on line 24
Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object in xxxxxxxx.php on line 27***

/////////////////////   PHP code /////////////////////////

```
 $thumb_count = 1;

 if ($thumb_count <= 50 ){
         $feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $youtube . '/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=50';


// read feed into SimpleXML object
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

// iterate over entries in feed
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) { 

  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

  // get video player URL
  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $watch = $attrs['url']; 

  // get video thumbnail
  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[3]->attributes();
  $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 

  // get <yt:duration> node for video length
  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
  $length = $attrs['seconds']; 

  // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
  $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
  $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 

  // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
  if ($gd->rating) {
    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
    $rating = $attrs['average']; 
  } else {
    $rating = 0; 
  } 

  $videoID = substr($watch, 31, 11); 
  $vidTitle = $media->group->title;
  $channel = $entry->author->name;
  $discript = $media->group->description;

 $select .= '<table width="150" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center"><font size="-1" >'.$media->group->title.'</font><br />
    <div class="thumbnail"><a href="xxxxxx?id='.$videoID.'">
          <img src="'.$thumbnail.'"width="120" height="90" /></a></div></div></td></tr>
</table><hr width="150" color="#FF0000" align="center" size="1" />';

 ++$thumb_count;
    }

 }
```

Now I have tried this **(with my limited knowladge)**

```
// get video player URL
$attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
if (($attrs =='') || (!$attrs)) { //////no need to double up, but wanted to make sure
continue ;
}
```

This then loads my page, but not properly, and still gives an error.

Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in xxxxxxxx.php on line 21

Now seeing as I need to go through the foreach loop many times and that there are a few nodes to go through, how can I check, bypass and continue without errors popping up?

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove PHP warning messages, you could use...

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: Burying the warnings is not a solution, because there is also a fatal error right after the warning.

Comment: @Shef, off course, but Fatal error was on his previous code, after he fix something (look again at the last part of his post) the remaining error(s) is just a php warning. So my answer is particullary for `continue without errors popping up`.

Comment: @toopay , I put that in my script and it seems to work with my "continue" function. Will still need to look into it to see if I am needing more or something else. Thank you. will do some more testing now to see if it breaks..... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$thumb_count = 1;
if ($thumb_count <= 50 ){
    $domain = "gdata.youtube.com";
    $path = 'feeds/api/users/' . $youtube . '/uploads?start-index=1&max-results=50';

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
    $sxml= loadXML2($domain, $path);
    if($sxml){
        // iterate over entries in feed
        foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) { 
              // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
              $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

              if($media->group->player->attributes()){
                  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
                  $watch = $attrs['url']; 
              }

              // get video thumbnail
              if($media->group->thumbnail[3]->attributes()){
                  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[3]->attributes();
                  $thumbnail = $attrs['url']; 
              }

              // get <yt:duration> node for video length
              if($media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007')){
                  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
                  if($yt->duration->attributes()){
                      $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
                      $length = $attrs['seconds']; 
                  }

                  // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
                  if($yt->statistics->attributes()){
                      $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
                      $viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 
                  }
              }

              // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
              if($entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005')){
                  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
                  if ($gd->rating & $gd->rating->attributes()) {
                    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
                    $rating = $attrs['average']; 
                  } else {
                    $rating = 0; 
                  } 
              }

              $videoID = substr($watch, 31, 11); 
              $vidTitle = $media->group->title;
              $channel = $entry->author->name;
              $discript = $media->group->description;

             $select .= '<table width="150" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><div align="center"><font size="-1" >'.$vidTitle.'</font><br />
                            <div class="thumbnail">
                                <a href="xxxxxx?id='.$videoID.'">
                                    <img src="'.$thumbnail.'"width="120" height="90" />
                                </a>
                            </div>
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr width="150" color="#FF0000" align="center" size="1" />';
             ++$thumb_count;
        }
    }  
}
// from: http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-file.php#97077
function loadXML2($domain, $path, $timeout = 30) { 
    $fp = fsockopen($domain, 80, $errno, $errstr, $timeout); 
    if($fp) { 
        // make request 
        $out = "GET $path HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
        $out .= "Host: $domain\r\n"; 
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
        fwrite($fp, $out); 

        // get response 
        $resp = ""; 
        while (!feof($fp)) { 
            $resp .= fgets($fp, 128); 
        } 
        fclose($fp); 
        // check status is 200 
        $status_regex = "/HTTP\/1\.\d\s(\d+)/"; 
        if(preg_match($status_regex, $resp, $matches) && $matches[1] == 200) {    
            // load xml as object 
            $parts = explode("\r\n\r\n", $resp);    
            return simplexml_load_string($parts[1]);                
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Not tried your script yet, but will do as soon as I have more time. Might not be needed, but will only know after some more testing. Thanks.

Comment: Noticed that your name did not go through, and as you had put code up for me, I thought you should get a reply notification. Will try out your code, but at the moment the "bypass" is working ( from "toopay" ). Not the best code practice, but if it works, cant knock it ;)

Comment: The point is that solve your problem so that it is appropriate for you. Good luck and if you have any questions with the response updates the thread.